# Haskell head/tail vs pattern matching

Tags: haskell

Here are two pieces of code.

Working:

```
joins :: [String] -> String -> String
joins [] _ = ""
joins [x] _ = x
joins xs d = head xs ++ d ++ (joins (tail xs) d)
```

Not working:

```
joins :: [String] -> String -> String
joins [] _ = ""
joins [x] _ = x
joins [x:xs] d = x ++ d ++ (joins xs d)
```

The error log for the latter is:

```
test.hs:4:18:
Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `Char'
In the first argument of `(++)', namely `x'
In the expression: x ++ d ++ (joins xs d)
In an equation for `joins':
    joins [x : xs] d = x ++ d ++ (joins xs d)

test.hs:4:35:
Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
Expected type: [String]
  Actual type: [Char]
In the first argument of `joins', namely `xs'
In the second argument of `(++)', namely `(joins xs d)'
In the second argument of `(++)', namely `d ++ (joins xs d)'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that `Data.List` offers the `intercalate` function for this.

Comment: The code above is for learning purposes, but in a real project I'll use the function you suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use parentheses, not brackets:

```
   -- vvvvvv
joins (x:xs) d = x ++ d ++ (joins xs d)
```

The pattern `[x:xs]` matches only with a list of length one, whose single element is a nonempty list `x:xs`.

Since yours is a list of strings, `[x:xs]` matches with `["banana"]` (where `x='b', xs="anana"`), with `["a"]` (`x='a', xs=""`) but not with `["banana", "split"]` nor with `[""]`.

This is clearly not what you want, so use plain parentheses.

(By the way, the parentheses in `... ++ (joins xs d)` are not needed: function application binds more than any binary operator in Haskell.)

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, this is at least the second question this month I've seen with `[x:xs]` rather than `(x:xs)`...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Indeed, this is a common mistake. I have also seen `f [x] = ...` where `x` is assumed to match with the input list many times. I always wonder what is the cause of the diffusion of these mistakes.